# Understanding Chrome Dev Tools timeline

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, jank

I'm trying to understand why I have several Long Frames reported by Chrome Dev Tools.

[image]

The first row (top of the call stack) in the flame chart are mostly `Timer Fired` events, triggered by `jQuery.Deferred()`s executing a bunch of `$(function(){ });` ready funcs.

If I dig into the jQuery source and replace their use of `setTimeout` with `requestAnimationFrame` the flame chart doesn't change much, I still get many of the rAFs firing within a single frame (as reported by dev tools) making long frames. I'd have expected doing the below pseudocode:

```
window.requestAnimationFrame(function() {
    // do stuff
});

window.requestAnimationFrame(function() {
    // do more stuff
});
```

to be executed on two difference animation frames. Is this not the case?

All of the JS that is executing is necessary, but what should I do to execute it as "micro tasks" (as hinted at, but not explained here https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/rendering/optimize-javascript-execution) when `setTimeout` and `rAF` don't seem to achieve this.

**Update**

Here's a zoomed in shot of one of the long frames that doesn't seem to have any reflows (forced or otherwise) in it. Why are all the rAF callbacks here being executed in one frame?

[image]

Comment: Apparently the first rAF exceeded frame budget so the browser switched to long frame and executed the second rAF. Use one rAF maybe: [Multiple requestAnimationFrame performance](//stackoverflow.com/a/17103945) As for microtasks, you can probably trigger one by using a MutationObserver with e.g. attributes:true on some invisible node and then changing an attribute.

Comment: @wOxxOm thanks, that makes sense theoretically, but i cant see how thats really happening, especially in the 2nd screenshot ive added ^

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Long frames are usually caused by **forced synchronous layouts**, which is when you (unintentionally) force a layout operation to happen early.

When you write to the DOM, the layout needs to be reflowed because it has been invalidated by the write operation. This usually happens at the next frame. However, if you try to read from the DOM, the layout happens early, in the current frame, in order to make sure that the correct value gets returned. When forced layout occurs, it causes long frames, leading to jank.

To prevent this from happening, you should only perform the write operations inside your `requestAnimationFrame` function. The read operations should be done outside of this, so as to avoid the browser doing an early layout.

[Diagnose Forced Synchronous Layouts](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/rendering-tools/forced-synchronous-layouts) is a nicely explained article, and has a simple example demo for detecting forced reflow in DevTools, and how to resolve it.

It might also be worth checking out [FastDom](https://github.com/wilsonpage/fastdom), which is a library for batching your read and write. It is basically a queuing system, and is more scalable.

**Additional Source:**
[What forces layout / reflow](https://gist.github.com/paulirish/5d52fb081b3570c81e3a), by Paul Irish, contains a comprehensive list of properties and methods that will force layout/reflow.

**Update:** As for the assumption that multiple `requestAnimationFrame` calls will execute callbacks on separate frames, this is not the case. When you have consecutive calls, the browser adds the callbacks to a document list of animation callbacks. When the browser goes to run the next frame, it traverses the document list and executes each of the callbacks, in the order they were added.

See [Animation Frames](https://www.w3.org/TR/html51/webappapis.html#animation-frames) from the HTML spec for more of the implementation details.

This means that you should avoid using the consecutive calls, especially where the callback function execution times combined exceed your frame budget. I think this would explain the long frames that aren't caused by reflow.

Comment: Hi @Gideon, thanks, ive updated the screenshot to show more height.
the 3 rightmost forced reflows are deliberate (due to the page design). What about the other frames that dont have forced reflows in them? Theyre also "long" but Chrome makes no complaints about forced reflows? Do you know why the multiple rAF callbacks are being batched into a single frame, making it long?

Comment: I had a little look at the spec and it turns out that each time the `requestAnimationFrame` function is called, the browser appends the animation callback to a list of callbacks at the document level, and then traverses and invokes them when it's time for the browser to run them. Therefore, you are effectively merging your callbacks into one frame, making it long.

Comment: Yep, just replaces all my `jquery.ready` `setTimeouts` with `fastdom.defer` and now theyre all executing in their own frames. winrar